# JavaScript and TypeScript scope issue

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use typescript, Knockout and azure mobile services to get some data. The problem is when I get data from azure, it's async and I can not get the viewmodel object any more. I think it's some scope/closure issue, please help me find the solution. It is null in the call back function for Done();

Here is my TypeScript code:

```
class pmViewModel {
    public welcomeMsg: string;
    public totalCount: number;
    constructor () {
        this.welcomeMsg = "";
    }
}

class Manager {
    client: any;
    portalVM: pmViewModel;
    constructor () {
        this.client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("url", "key");
        this.portalVM = new pmViewModel();
    }

    LoadData() {
        console.log("load data for management portal");
        this.portalVM.welcomeMsg = "Hello";
        this.portalVM.totalCount = 0;
        var dataTable = this.client.getTable('dataTable');

        dataTable.take(1).includeTotalCount().read().done(this.populateTotal,this.portalVM);

        ko.applyBindings(this.portalVM);
        };

        populateTotal(result, vm) {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(vm); //null here
            this.portalVM.totalCount = 100000;////this is also null
        }
}
```

and generated JavaScript code:

```
var pmViewModel = (function () {
    function pmViewModel() {
        this.welcomeMsg = "";
    }
    return pmViewModel;
})();
var Manager = (function () {
    function Manager() {
        this.client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("url", "key");
        this.portalVM = new pmViewModel();
    }
    Manager.prototype.LoadData = function () {
        console.log("load data for management portal");
        this.portalVM.welcomeMsg = "Hello";
        this.portalVM.totalCount = 0;
        var dataTable = this.client.getTable('dataTable');
        dataTable.take(1).includeTotalCount().read().done(this.populateTotal, this.portalVM);
        ko.applyBindings(this.portalVM);
    };
    Manager.prototype.populateTotal = function (result, vm) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(vm);
        this.portalVM.totalCount = 100000;
    };
    return Manager;
})();
```

Comment: You need to show where the error is occurring.

Comment: In the Done method callback (I put some comments there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant line here:

```
dataTable.take(1).includeTotalCount().read().done(this.populateTotal,this.portalVM);
```

You need to capture the 'this' binding of `populateTotal` since it's going to be invoked as a callback without context.

Option 1:

```
[etc...].done((result, vm) => this.populateTotal(result, vm), this.portalVM);
```

Option 2:

```
[etc...].done(this.populateTotal.bind(this), this.portalVM);
```

Comment: Your solution looks correct, but all functions have their own context. The issues is that the `this` value of *LoadData* isn't set to the object that the OP expects. The value of `this` is set by the call, which is what you've done.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I made slight modification.

done((result) => this.populateTotal(result), this.portalVm)
populateTotal(result) {
            this.portalVm.totalCount = result.totalCount;
            ko.applyBindings(this.portalVm);
        }

Comment: Can you please explain a bit exactly what does that do "this.portalVM" in the function call.